# Python I/O replacing words in the line

Tags: python, io

hey I've wrote this code in python and it iterates through the selected text file and reads it. My objective is to read the file, and then write the file on a new file and replace the word "winter" with nothing. or rather delete the word from the second revised file. I have two txt files called odetoseasons and odetoseasons_censored the contents of these two files are identical before the program starts. which is

```
I love winter
I love spring
Summer, Fall and winter again.
```

/This is the python file named readwrite.py WHen i run the program it keeps the contents in odetoseasons but somehow deletes the contents of odetoseasons_censored.txt not sure why/

```
# readwrite.py
# Demonstrates reading from a text file and writing to the other

filename = input("Enter file name (without extension): ")
fil1 = filename+".txt"
fil2 = filename+"_censored.txt"
bad_word = ['winter']

print("\nLooping through the file, line by line.")
in_text_file = open(fil1, "r")
out_text_file = open(fil2,"w")
for line in in_text_file:
    print(line)
    out_text_file.write(line)
in_text_file.close()
out_text_file.close()

out_text_file = open(fil2,"w")
for line in fil2 :
     if "winter" in line:
        out_text_file.write(line)
        line.replace("winter", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two errors in your code. Firstly the function a.replace() returns an object with the replaced word and not alter the original object. Secondly you are trying to read a file you have opened in 'w' mode, which is not possible. If you need to both read and write you should use 'r+' mode.

Here is the correct code(and more compact one) that you can use :-

```
filename = input("Enter file name (without extension): ")
fil1 = filename+".txt"
fil2 = filename+"_censored.txt"
bad_word = ['winter']

print("\nLooping through the file, line by line.")
in_text_file = open(fil1, "r")
out_text_file = open(fil2,"w")
for line in in_text_file:
    print(line)
    line_censored = line.replace("winter","")
    print(line_censored)
    out_text_file.write(line_censored)
in_text_file.close()
out_text_file.close()
```